# Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такую форму в CSS?

Tags: css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такую форму в CSS?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто img внутри div и обоим добавить стиль border-radius, наверное?

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 60% 10px 30% 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    width:140px;
}
img {
    border-radius: 60% 10px 30% 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}



<div> 
<img src='...' alt=''>
</div>
```

поиграйтесь с margin и padding  и углами закругления и получите любую форму.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ff355c;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 75% 10% 35% 15%;
}
```

```html
<div> :) </div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо :)

Comment: @Olga Если ответ годится, отметьте вопрос решенным.